# Windows could not start Windows Process Activation Service service on Local Computer Error 9

Tags: .net, iis, was

WAS Error 9: the storage control block address is invalid

[image]

Error in IIS while starting the Default Web Site

[image]

I installed IIS in my local machine and when I tried to start the Default Web Site from `inetmgr` it showed error to start WAS and W3SVC services.

When I tied to start WAS service from services.msc getting error

> "Error 9: the storage control block address is invalid"

Answer (score 0):

Error 9 can be caused by a variety of reasons. It is usually due to the system failing to properly run a program or application. It can be hardware or related to the installation or maintenance of Windows Operating System. Corrupted files, malfunctioned hardware, corrupted Registry, etc., can be the prime reasons for the occurrence of Windows System Errors. you need to troubleshooting this issue with process monitor and event viewer. You need to check which file would probably corrupted.

About second error you can try to restart W3SVC.

1. Right click on the bar on the bottom of the screen
2. Observe a menu pops up, then choose Task Manager
3. Choose the Services tab
4. Find the W3SVC service under Name
5. Right click that service and choose start

Comment: Thank you for response. Until WAS service is not started we can not start W3SVC as this is dependent on WAS.  Can you please help to troubleshoot Error 9 with Event Viwer

Comment: You have to check if there is an error message in the Event viewer first.

Comment: Error from Event Viewer : The Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered an error while handling key generation. This will prevent WAS from starting corrently. The data field contains the error number

Comment: you can try to  resolve the issue using the guideline given by Microsort on the reported id, If you still can’t solve the problem, I suggest you try my method above.